# RabbitMQ test consumer is Alive

Tags: java, rabbitmq

I have a JAVA  application which creates consumers that listen to rabbitmq . I need to know the started consumer is still working fine and if not then i need to restart the consumer.

Is their any way i can do that. Currently my main application creates an Executor thread pool and passes this executor while creating new connection.

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(30);
Connection connection = factory.newConnection(executor);
```

The main method then create 30 consumerApp object by calling constructor with new channel as argument and call the listen() method

```
for(int i=0;i<=30;i++) {
 ConsumerApp consumer = new ConsumerApp(i,connection.createChanell());
 consumer.listen() }
```

The listen method in consumerApp listen to a queue and start a DefaultConsumer Object which simply prints the received message

```
listen() { 
  try {
  channel.queueDeclare("test-queue-name", false, false, false, null);
  }
catch {
  System.out.println("Exception on creating Queue")
  }
Consumer consumer = new DefaultConsumer(this.channel) {
@Override
        public void handleDelivery(String consumerTag, Envelope envelope, AMQP.BasicProperties properties,
                byte[] body) throws IOException {
            String message = new String(body, "UTF-8");
            System.out.println(" [x] Received Message in consumer '"+consumerId+" "+  message + "'");
        }
    };
 //Now starting the consumer
  try {
    channel.basicConsume(QUEUE_NAME, true, consumer);   
   }
    catch (ShutdownSignalException | IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
```

I want to know is their any way i can check the consumer is active . My idea is to catch the shutdown signal exception and recreate the consumer object and recall the listen method . Is this necessary as rabbitmq auto recovers and connnect back. ? But how can i ensure this ?

Is this any way achievable using the threadpool passed to rabbitmq connector.

I am using latest version of rabbitmq client 5.3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Consumer` has [different methods](https://rabbitmq.github.io/rabbitmq-java-client/api/current/com/rabbitmq/client/Consumer.html) that can help you track the state of your consumer. You're likely to be interested in `handleConsumeOk` and in `handleCancel`.
[Automatic connection recovery](http://www.rabbitmq.com/api-guide.html#recovery) will indeed re-register consumers after a connection failure, but that doesn't prevent you from following their state manually to e.g. expose some information on JMX.

Comment: Thanks Arnaud Cogoluègnes . I extended the Default consumer class and overridden the handleCancel methods